# How to get GPS Position of mobile user triggered remotely from a Website

Tags: android, ios, gps, push-notification

One user manages mobile users via a website interface. By clicking on a button on that website I have to display the current position of the chosen mobile user. So what I need to do is send something to the mobile app to trigger sending the GPS position to my server. My website then starts polling the database to check every 10sec whether the GPS coordinates have arrived.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use Push Notifications for this purpose? I already implemented it, so everything would be there.
2. Can I do that silently, so that the mobile user doesn't get notified? I have found something called Silent Push Notifications - is that what I'm searching for?

I have to do it on Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android it is definitelly possible. There is no default behavior (such as alerts/badges/sounds) to notify the user of the app that they got a notification. When the app gets a push notification, a broadcast receiver is created and its `onReceive` method executed. You can have whatever logic you need in that method, though if you require a logic that requires a long time to execute (such as server calls), you should start an intent service from the receiver and do you logic in the service (get the location of the device and send it to your server).

On iOS I believe it is possible since iOS7. Until iOS7, the application logic for handling the push notification would only be triggered after the user clicks on the notification/alert to open the app. iOS7 enable the app to do background processing as a result of the arriving push notification. I believe you should use the `{"aps":{"content-available"=1}}` payload in this case (which is used for `background content downloads`), since you don't want any payload that would be displayed to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how can I do that for iOS 6? Is there another method I can use?

Comment: You can't do it with push notifications in iOS6. You can run a background service that tracks location for your app and send it to your server periodically, but that won't be on-demand (i.e. your server can't request the app on a specific device to send a location update).

Answer (score 1):

For android you have some ways to implement the push service:

1. GCM  - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html:
2. MQTT - http://mqtt.org/
3. implement your own persistent connection.

All of them have their advantages. If you need a ack that the mobile client got the msg you should use MQTT. It is also faster than GCM because of less overhead and you don't have the GCM server in between. On the other hand GCM is easy to implement and you don't have to worry about the persistent TCP connection from your server.

Also the silent way is possible because you just trigger a service each time. so if you don't want a notification, the user don't get it.

I am not sure about iOS. For iOS6 it was not possible to implement your own service, which is necessary to "wake up" your app. I am not sure about about iOS7. So for iOS6 you definitely need to use Apples push server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, haven't heard of MQTT yet. It's a bad thing, that I have so many opportunities on Android, but iOS only provides something starting from iOS 7.